# GDI+: What's wrong when I draw a image of pure red color with black background?

Tags: c++, windows, gdi+

Here is my code：

```
ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;
Gdiplus::GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);
auto outBuffer_ = new char[1920 * 1080 * 4];
memset(outBuffer_, 0, 1920 * 1080 * 4);
auto outBuffer = new char[1920* 1080 * 4];
for (int i = 0; i < 1920 * 1080; i++){
    outBuffer[0 + i * 4] = 255;//a
    outBuffer[1 + i * 4] = 255;//r
    outBuffer[2 + i * 4] = 0;//g
    outBuffer[3 + i * 4] = 0;//b
}
auto pBitmap_A =new Gdiplus::Bitmap(static_cast<INT>(1920),
    static_cast<INT>(1080), static_cast<INT>(4 * 1920), PixelFormat32bppARGB, reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(outBuffer_));
auto pGrap = new Gdiplus::Graphics(pBitmap_A);

Gdiplus::Image* img = new Gdiplus::Bitmap(static_cast<INT>(1920), static_cast<INT>(1080),
    static_cast<INT>(4 * 1920), PixelFormat32bppARGB, reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(outBuffer));

Gdiplus::Status sts = pGrap->DrawImage(img, 0, 0, 1920, 1080);
FILE *p = fopen("f.rgb", "wb");
fwrite(outBuffer_, 1920 * 1080 * 4, 1, p);
```

I want to a pure red color image. But the file is all zero.It is just a black image.

However when I want to a pure blue color image

```
outBuffer[0 + i * 4] = 255;//a
outBuffer[1 + i * 4] = 0;//r
outBuffer[2 + i * 4] = 0;//g
outBuffer[3 + i * 4] = 255;//b
```

I got a normal blue image. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Since you're already using GDI+, wouldn't it be easier to use its high-level drawing functions, instead of manipulating raw pixel data?

Comment: I just want to know what's wrong with my code. why blue is ok?

Comment: Are you sure about the byte ordering? If you change the test to do green instead of red or blue, does it work or do you get black? If you get black, then the byte ordering is probably BGRA instead of your expected ARGB.

Comment: You've got the color channels backwards, it is black because you set A = 0.  Machines are little-endian.  Using uint instead of char is the trivial, and fast, solution

Comment: Use BGRA (the native bitmap format on all machines). You can use a union struct for BGRA and set the colour to 0xFF. It will take care of the rest of the layout: https://pastebin.com/tzyfPhK3

Comment: @HansPassant Do you mean change the code to be auto outBuffer = new UINT32[1920* 1080 ];
 for (int i = 0; i < 1920 * 1080; i++){
  outBuffer[i] = 255 << 8| 255;
 }

Comment: @Brandon, when i can find the definition of Color .

Comment: @funs; Color is just `unsigned int`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I use outBuffer[0 + i * 4] = 0;//a
outBuffer[1 + i * 4] = 0;//r
outBuffer[2 + i * 4] = 0;//g
outBuffer[3 + i * 4] = 255;//b also got blue image